# OnTriggerStay2D performance/alternatives

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I got a simple "OnTouch" script on my enemies, which knocks back the player if they come in contact. The player then gets invincible for a short time. Something like this:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider) {
    if (collider.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) {

        if (Time.time > isInvincible) {
            isInvincible = Time.time + invincibleTimer;

            if (enemy.IsFacingRight) {
                player.SetVelocity(knockback * Vector2.right);
            } else {
                player.SetVelocity(knockback * Vector2.left);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(SetVelocity is just a method i use to set.. velocity)

The problem with this is when the player gets invincible after been pushed away. While invincible you can then run on top of an enemy and stay there, even after the invincible timer runs out. Which i guess makes sense since it only triggers on enter.

Using the same code but inside a "OnTriggerStay2D", works as expected. You get pushed away, go invincible, run on top of an enemy, invincible runs out and you then get pushed away out of the enemy.

But having multiple enemies running around with OnTriggerStay colliding with different objects feels like it would be bad performance wise? Is there any more efficient way to do this? Or is TriggerStay the way to go?

Comment: well you could trigger the invicibility and on a count down remove it, using either an invoke, or coroutine, which then allows for it to be reactivated after the cool down etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I found is manually tracking the collisions like this:

```
List<Collider2D> hitColliders = new List<Collider2D>();

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision) {
    if (hitColliders.Contains(collision)) { return; }
    hitColliders.Add(collision);
}
void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision) {
    hitColliders.Remove(collision);
}

// Perform operations to the colliders.
void Update() { 
    foreach (var col in hitColliders) { DoStuff(col); }
}
```

Comment: I'm kinda getting the same result. Maybe I'm missing something, but by just logging 'col' in the foreach i still get a lot of hits. For example collisions with the ground is still triggered every frame on update

Comment: Ok, i think i get it now.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Although you may not run into performance problems even with the solution you have now, if you do in the future you can try using [Physics.IgnoreLayerCollision](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.IgnoreLayerCollision.html):  
At the start of your `invincibleTimer` call:
`IgnoreLayerCollision(playerLayer, enemyLayer, true);`

And at the end of your timer call:
`IgnoreLayerCollision(playerLayer, enemyLayer, false);`
And acording to the docs:

> IgnoreLayerCollision will reset the trigger state of affected
>   colliders, so you might receive OnTriggerExit and OnTriggerEnter
>   messages in response to calling this.

This means that when you call IgnoreLayerCollision(false), `OnTriggerEnter` will be called again, even if you are already on top of an enemy. This is exactly the behaviour you are after.